# How do I use security component in CakePHP?

Tags: security, cakephp

How do I use security component in CakePHP? Can any one give me good tutorial?

Comment: What for? http://book.cakephp.org/view/175/Security-Component

Answer (score 2):

Follow the CakePHP Cookbook, but include the following in your app controller's `beforeFilter()` function:

```
$this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_blackHole';
```